# infinite dimensional hilbert space - uniqueness of series expansion

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

A function $f(x)$ is expanded in a series of orthonormal functions

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \varphi_n(x) $$

Show that the series expansion is unique for a given set of $\varphi_n(x) $. The functions $\varphi_n(x)$ are being taken here as the basis vectors in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

I do not know how to start this formally. I am thinking that since $\varphi_n(x) $ are basis vectors then for all $\varphi_n(x) $ in a particular vector space there exist unique scalars $a_n$ such that $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \varphi_n(x) $$. Does this make it a unique expansion? i'm so confused and not sure about my statement since i got it form a finite dimensional vector. Will this be the same for infinite-dimensional ones? Please help.

Comment: Hint; you can  compute the $a_n $ explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Convergence in this context means convergence in norm. Therefore,
$$
         \left|\left(f-\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n\varphi_n,\varphi_k\right)\right|
              \le \left\|f-\sum_{n=0}^{N}\varphi_{n}\right\|\|\varphi_{k}\|\rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as } N\rightarrow\infty.
$$
For $N \ge k$, the left side is constant with respect to $N$ and is equal to
$$
              \left|(f,\varphi_{k})-a_{k}\right|,
$$
which implies that $(f,\varphi_{k})=a_{k}$ for all $k \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what it means to be an orthonormal basis, the $a_n$ are precisely the inner product of the $\phi_n$ with $f$ by orthonormality.

Comment: Is the hint for me? If not it should be a comment on the original question. In addition there's not a priori a computation to give the $a_n$ unless you are assuming this is $L^2$ and you are choosing a basis.

Comment: I dont think this is a good hint, after all just because that is one series representation, does not mean there could not be another. (1,0,0,0...) sums to the same as (1/2,1/2,0,0...) so what exactly prevents that from happening here?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. In the question a fixed basis is chosen, and they are asking about the uniqueness of a representation with respect to a chosen orthonormal basis. Your example doesn't seem (to me) to have anything to do with this, it's more about the value of a specific functional on summable sequences...

Comment: But to be charitable: if you're asking about the uniqueness of the expression, it follows easily from the fact that the \phi_n are orthogonal.